# React navigation 5 authentication flow using class component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I am using react navigation 5 in class component
Where I have two stack for BeforeLogin stack which include SignIn and Sign Up
and another stack have different Bottom tab screen's stack.
But can not navigate to the afterlogin home stack using this.props.navigation.navigate in login function .

Is there any solution?

Comment: You should add some code and explain your issue in more detail. I however think you're looking for something like this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/ ?

Comment: put your first try here so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, just add routes conditionally to your navigator. So if your user is authenticated, pass the routes to your Main Stack. If he is not authenticated, pass the routes to your login/signup stack.

*Example from their documentation*

```
return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {state.userToken == null ? ( 
      // No token found, user isn't signed in
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignInScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Sign in',
          // When logging out, a pop animation feels intuitive
          // You can remove this if you want the default 'push' animation
          animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
        }}
      />
    ) : (
      // User is signed in
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Notice that the routes are conditional, like I said. If the user authentication state changes, you don't even need to call `navigate`. The state change will rerender this `<Route />` component and navigate to the HomeScreen by itself.

Comment: Here's a small app I built that has that feature. Check out the `src/router.js` file https://bitbucket.org/sirkadogan/empresas-react-native/src/master/

Comment: Yeah right now I maintain a global state for auth token .now it's working .thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made a mistake. I thought there is switch navigation concept which is include in navigation v4.Then I have maintained a global state for auth token after that it works . Actually navigation v5 is much better.